# Printing report on a pre-printed stationery

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, jasper-reports

I am into a brain twisting scenario and had done lot of googling but failed...

I need to print a report on a pre-printed stationery. I tried jasper reports with mysql database but it did not help me. While i am trying to measure the actual stationery and trying to align it with the measurement in jasper reports. WHile printing it goes haywire. I also tried rendering it through html and css but results are way to awkward. Can someone please help me with this problem. Crystal Reports have a width only of 7. something inches but my stationery is of A4 size sheet. Hence did not actually help me.

If someone can atleast tell me any other alternative or if anyone has actually faced this situation and have had overcome it. It would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really "how do I precisely control the layout of my report pages?"

For that to work you need to be working with a page-layout-capable reporting program. Both Jasper and Crystal can do that. They both are capable of taking the "infinite scroll" of your SQL result sets and "cutting the scroll" into cut-paper-size chunks.

CSS and HTML for this? No... far too hard.

You can control Crystal's and Jasper's page size. You can set margins and page sizes, and place whitespace in their page layouts where the printing of your stationery lies. I know Crystal has the concept of a page layout library: this will let your co-workers use the results of your page layout work if that's needed.

Many people designing high-volume reports scan the graphic elements of the stationery they're using and have the report program render those elements ... in other words they "fake" the stationery.  That is one reliable way to make stationery-printed reports, especially if you have to crank out a lot of them: it's easier for production if they don't have to remember to put the paper in the printer the right way up, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, So as far as i understand you want me to set a background image of the scanned stationery and then render the layout. I will definitely try that. Please reply back if i have correctly understood you

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in the past.

Essentially, you need to position the fields [database|formula|sql-expression] in a way that print in the desired location on your printed form.  I used the `details` section, but a `group header` or `group footer` section would also work.

To set the paper size, select `File > Page Setup...`, then select `A4`.  If necessary, you can create a custom page size by selecting `User Defined Size`.